# Files linked in HTML not loaded in Java server

Tags: java, html, css, intellij-idea, server

I ran into a problem when I tried to create a local server using Java's Socket and ServerSocket.

The problem is that when the server receives the request and returns the HTML file, it apparently cannot locate any linked files in the HTML code (including the .png image and the .css stylesheet) which means my web page shows up with no formatting and images. The exception thrown is FileNotFound.

The code below is what I used to stream in the HTML file (named index.html) and transfer it to the output stream.

```java
public class HttpServer {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket sSocket;
        Socket cSocket;
        PrintWriter out;
        Scanner in;

        while (true) {
            
            // set up streams & readers
            sSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
            cSocket = sSocket.accept();
            OutputStream oStream = cSocket.getOutputStream();
            out = new PrintWriter(oStream, true);
            in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(cSocket.getInputStream()));
            
            // read in HTTP request, filepath and protocol
            String command = in.next();
            String fileName = in.next();
            String protocol = in.next();

            // if filepath is only "/", point to index.html
            if (fileName.equals("/"))
                fileName = "Resources/index.html";

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            // return
            out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); // placeholder status
            out.println("Server: My Server");
            out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            fis.transferTo(oStream);

            // flush and close
            out.flush();
            in.close();
            out.close();
            cSocket.close();
            sSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is what I used to link the .css to the index.html file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" content="text/css" href="./myStyles.css"/>
```

And the folder structure as well:

```
.
└── HttpServer
    ├── HttpServer.iml
    ├── Resources
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── myStyles.css
    ├── out
    │   └── production
    │       └── HttpServer
    │           ├── HttpServer.class
    │           ├── index.html
    │           └── myStyles.css
    └── src
        └── HttpServer.java
```

The IDE is IntelliJ.

I've been banging my head against the wall all day trying to find out what went wrong, but no explanations seem convincing enough in my situation. As far as I'm concerned, the most possible reason is that the FileInputStream somehow moves the current working folder to somewhere in the machine which renders the relative file path invalid. However, as my understanding, if the FileInputStream did actually read the index.html file, it should be able to read the .css file as well.

I'm guessing the problem does not lie with the index.html file because when I open the HTML file directly by double-clicking on it from the file browser, everything (formatting & images) loads just fine. It only becomes a problem if the file is passed through Java's server, so I suspect it has something to do with the Java classes or IDE settings which are totally unfamiliar to me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your current server appears to be hardcoded to only serve `index.html` (since `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Resources/index.html");` ignores what the client asked for and returns `index.html`).

Comment: Please include the complete contents of HttpServer.java

Comment: Pretty sure you also need a blank line before you start serving `index.html`, and you don't seem to be serving important headers like `Content-Type`.

Comment: I just updated my post with the full content of the .java file.

To be clear, I actually didn't use hard code in my actual file – I only did that here because I wanted to simplify my code and exclude all kinds of stuff that are not needed. Apparently, that wasn't a smart move. I also served some additional headers as @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- suggested as well but it still didn't seem to be working out. Really appreciate any additional input!

Comment: Just to confirm: Is the purpose of this code to learn about how Java networking and the HTTP protocol work?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Yes, it is!

Comment: Then I suggest using Postman or a similar tool to manually perform the requests and see exactly what's being returned and how it's interpreted.

Comment: Just skimming your code, it looks as though the file names are not going to get the `Resources` directory as a prefix, but you haven't mentioned *which* path is throwing the `FileNotFoundException`